# Difference between High level design and low level design and their components

Tags: php, architecture, software-design

I am trying to design High level design and low level design for a web application (PHP). But I am stuck with what is the basic difference between them. And also what are their components. And also where does the database design and business logics lie between two.

Comment: If you can't even really define these terms, maybe you shouldn't worry too much about them. Without context I couldn't really tell you either what they mean, but I'd still design your application.

Comment: Think this better suited to programmers.se

Comment: @deceze Its not just about this application I would like to know about those things in more depth. I've posted this question hoping that I would get better answers to make my views and concepts clearer about them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, as many people there are as many answers and opinions you will probably get but here are my $0.02.

In my practice high-level design has been identifying major goals of the application, splitting them to separate global modules, sections of your website, global functionality blocks addressing particular customer/user needs. Also here I would identify the global business logic of the application. Global database design can also be a part of it, but not down to the tables or databases, but rather which data will be stored and which not, how long, etcetera.

Low-level design will in turn take each building block that came out of high-level design and break it up to even smaller parts, where you'd be thinking about your data strictures, PHP classes, database tables, data exchange and so on.